# Create a date column from the month and year and a static day

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have 'Year' and 'Month' columns in my SQL table. No column for Day. Example below.

| Year | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 2010 | 10 |
| 2008 | 8 |
| 2021 | 11 |
| Null | Null |
| 2009 | 2 |

I would like to create a 'Date' column (YYYY-MM-DD) where YYYY='Year', MM='Month', and  DD=15. So, the values of the newly created 'Date' column will be as shown below:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2010-10-15 |
| 2008-8-15 |
| 2021-11-15 |
| Null |
| 2009-2-15 |

I tried the following code

> CONCAT(Year,'-',Month,'-',15) as Date

and got as below

| Date |
| --- |
| 2010-10-15 |
| 2008-8-15 |
| 2021-11-15 |
| --15 |
| 2009-2-15 |

I would like to get `Null` for the 'Date' where either year, or month, or both are `Null`. I also would like to use the newly created values in the 'Date' column as a date.

Please help

Comment: You really shouldn't delete a question just to re-ask it, but I also think your original question should have been reopened hence I have answered this.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. Unfortunately the original question had not been reopened.

Comment: Generally it can take some time for a closed question to go through the reopen queue (were talking days, if not more), not hours or minutes. This is why it's so important that you make your question complete to start with, and if not (and this is raised very shortly after the question is posted) then addressing the problems quickly can avoid closure or result in a quick reopen while users are still engaged in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in the comments of your original question, use `CASE` to detect the `NULL` situation, and if not `NULL` use `DATEFROMPARTS` e.g.

```
case when [Year] is not null and [Month] is not null
then datefromparts([Year], [Month], 15)
else null
end
```

Comment: Providing a column name worked. Thank you so much for your tremendous help.